# How do I save text to the page

Tags: php, html, facebook

Normally a comment system requires the commenter to enter a comment into a textarea, than submit to post and save to the site i.e facebook commenting system. I am trying to achieve something similar. Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Enter Comment</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>

<form method="get" id="testformid">
    <input type="Share!" />
</form> 
<textarea form ="testformid" name="taname" id="taid" cols="35" wrap="soft">/textarea>

<p id="par">Hi</p>

<button id="btn1" onclick="document.getElementById('par').innerHTML =  
document.getElementById('inp').value;">Share your story!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that I want the text that is printed on the white area of the site to be saved if the commenter decides to add more text instead of replacing the previous comment. Also if someone else were to comment it would join with the previous comment and become a mass text of such.

Comment: The code you have there is only functional client side. So text you enter won't be seen by others. And text entered by others wouldn't be visible to you.

Comment: Thank you. See this is the problem. I don't know how to make it visible on the clients side AND the rest of the users.

Comment: You'll need some sort of server that stores the messages in some sort of database and then when the page is accessed it should get the messages from that database. As for the How to do that, that'd be too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your help though. Very much appreciated. Just a quick question. This code would be functional if I just added a server of some sort as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement server side code (I personally prefer PHP).

You will need a [database](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_create_database.htm) in order to do this running on SQL (PHPMyAdmin is good).

It works like this:

1) [Connect your php script to your database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

2) [Save your users comment to the database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), and you would save their comments [using a HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

3) When a user loads your page, you need some code to [display all of the rows](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Some things to read into:

[A good PHP course](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php)

[A good SQL course](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page)

Nobody here will write you a full working program to do what you want above, youll have to do some research and learn how to use PHP and SQL

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If I may quickly ask without wasting your time, When you said I'll need to implement a (php) server side code, what relevance does the database in SQL have? Thank you again!

Comment: @JelzBellz no worries at all! A database is a collection of 'information'. Just as we write code to make programs, websites, servers do what we want, a database too has its own 'language', this is called SQL (Standard Query Language) - so things like `SELECT` is a 'key word' in its language, and allows us to interface with the database. And I use PHPMyAdmin because it is great to link in with PHP on the server (or on your local computer).

Comment: Oh, that makes alot more sense now. Thank you very much, I really do appreciate your help!